# Hierarchy for higher order formulas

Tags: logic, set-theory

In Kanamori’s book, *The Higher Infinite*, corollary 6.9(a) states that for any $n\in\omega$ there is a $\Pi^1_{n+1}$ sentence which characterizes $\Pi^1_n$-indescribablity.

I had have a question on following his proof. Using a $\Pi^1_n$ formula $\psi_{1n}(X,Y)$ with $X$ type 2 variable and $Y$ type 1 that comes from the previous propostion 6.8, which tells a kind of $\Pi^1_n$ satisfaction, he argued that one can take

> $\forall X\forall Y(\psi_{1n}(X,Y)\to\exists\alpha>0(\alpha\textrm{ is limit }\wedge\ \langle V_\alpha,\in\rangle\models\psi_{1n}(X\cap V_\alpha,Y)))$.

Then he said by $\forall X$ and the occurrence of $\psi_{1n}(X,Y)$ to the left of $\to$, the above sentence is $\Pi^1_{n+1}$.

However, how can I treat $\forall Y$? $Y$ is a type 1 variable, and the definition of $\Pi^m_n$ formula in his book is with starting a block of type $m+1$ universal quantifiers, which seems not to allow lower type.

May I change the order of qunatifiers, or the definition needs to be modified to allow to starting with lower types?

Thanks in advance.